# Can we stop Page_Load on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate, pageload

I have created a password reset URL. I want that URL to show some alert box if user access that URL more than 3 times(means load that URL more than 3 times).I have set a if condition in `Page_Load()` function of the page. My problem is on reset button click page_load is calling and increasing the attempt and i want the attempt to increase only on URL load. In `page_load` i am increasing the attempt by 1 and storing it in db.

I have tried `if(!postback)` but postBack is `True` for every url load as well as Button click.

My button code:

```
 " asp:Button ID="btnReset" runat="server" Text="Reset Password" onclick="btnReset_Click"  /"
```

Comment: `this.IsPostBack` is `true` for every access except the first access. actually if you dont use Refresh and enter URL in address bar then the `this.IsPostBack` will be `false`.

Answer (score 1):

Please place condition in page_load like :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          if(!Page.IsPostBack)
             {

               //Please place your code here

              }
     }
```

Comment: This will work if I open a link in new tab.But while reloading the link...it is giving IsPostBack=true